# What is this Antique Brass Instrument on display at the Musical Instrument Museum in Brussels, Belgium?

Tags: instruments, brass

Does anyone know what type of instrument this is? It looks like some type of Euphonium, but obviously very different.

[image]

Comment: It's obviously a sousoxaphonepet. ;)

Comment: Take a look at this https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:7_Bells,_Musical_Instrument_Museum,_Brussels.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin you tricked me into searching for sousoxaphonepet

Comment: @JimM So does that mean it's a prototype, or one-off? Basically an instrument without a name or category?!

Comment: @1_am_Jack - sorry... kind of :P I'd imagined it was a one-off. I hadn't imagined it was actually an Adolphe Sax one-off.

Comment: Please can we find a video of it being played...?

Comment: It's not a one-off, its a mock-up of the packaging of a marketing campaign for a six-pack, plus a seventh "buy one get one free" offer thrown in.

Comment: I saw this instrument drawn in a Dr. Seuss book when I was a kid.

Comment: I vote for  Hydraphone, in honor of Hercules' labors

Comment: It's clearly a Whoville Horn

Answer (score 3):

The Musical Instrument Museums Online Catalog has an entry for this instrument [here](http://www.mimo-international.com/MIMO/doc/IFD/URN_REPOX_KMKG.BE_MIM_RMAH_119428_NL).

Made in Paris in 1876 by Adolphe Sax, it's simply titled "trombone with valves."

This instrument's entry on [Carmentis](http://carmentis.kmkg-mrah.be/eMP/eMuseumPlus?service=ExternalInterface&lang=en) unfortunately doesn't provide us with much extra information. Though, oddly, despite being named "valve trombone," it's classified under "valve trumpets." (Perhaps there's a distinction here among instrument classification systems that I'm not aware of.)

Comment: It reminds me of a Martinstrompete but with more valves and a lot more plumbing. I believe that the Martinstrompete is in the Schalmei family.

Comment: Is 'valve trumpet' tautological?

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe it distinguishes from something like a bugle that has no valves?

Comment: Maybe the naming conventions hadn't quite been nailed yet? I mean, what at the time would you have called a saxophone.. especially if someone else had invented an almost identical one concurrently?

Comment: @Tim "valve trumpet" wasn't tautological until somebody invented valves - several centuries after somebody invented the trumpet!

Comment: @alephzero - and I thought a trumpet was a horn with valves. wasn't the original horn one which only produced harmonics, and the valves made it capable of playing the in-between notes, and the *trumpet* was born?

Comment: @Tetsujin - if it had been invented by a Mr. Tele, it could have been called a ........ Do I need to finish?

Comment: @Richard - that was the point. A bugle ain't a trumpet.

Comment: @Tim - look up "natural trumpet"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a trombone's bore profile differs from a trumpet, so even a putative "bass trumpet" would have a different sound.  Consider the difference between trumpet, cornet, and flugelhorn, for example.

Comment: It's not to do with bore - a trombone has seven slide positions. The instrument illustrated has seven bells. So each valve is used individually rather than in combination with the others, and represents a slide position. It's different to a valve trumpet because that uses valves in combination - and there are seven combinations.

Answer (score 2):

When manufacturing techniques got good enough for valves to be practical, there was a crazy rush to try to invent fully chromatic versions of existing brass instruments. Inventors tried lots of different schemes, and most didn't make it. This seems to be one of those failed experiments.

The one-bell-per-note is reminiscent of the Schalmei:

[image: 16-bell schalmei]

And the trombone range and position of the valves is reminiscent of the cavalry trombone:

[image]

Adolphe Sax did quite a bit of work experimenting with one-valve-per-note systems. They solve the inherent tuning problems of modern brass instruments, but the added weight and complexity isn't worth it.